# How to overwrite a inbuilt control method in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with c# Windows application and in one of requrements I need to chage the parameters of a method of the inbuilt c#.net control. can any one please help me regarding this.

See the Line 1 below the custom tooltip have method called "show" here it will take only controls as the references to show the  Tooltip I need to change the method some thing like Line-2

```
1. CustomTooltip.Show("", control1);
2. CustomTooltip.Show("", SomeText);
```

Comment: What control what method? try first! then ask :) If you've tried show the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to know about [WinForm](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/10/13/winforms-user-controls-101.aspx) user control. Please visit this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) page for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could derive from the control that you want to extend:

```
public class MyTextBox: TextBox
{
    ... override the methods you need
}
```